# How to deploy Azure Function app including code using ARM template from Azure marketplace

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, azure-marketplace

I want to deploy a Function App including code using an ARM template **that is going to be published in the Azure Marketplace as a Managed App**.

I've seen in the docs that you can add a **sourcecontrols** element in the ARM template that you can use to point to e.g. a GitHub repository. However, I don't want to use a repository, I want to code to be uploaded to the Function App.

I also know you can upload the code using the Azure CLI or powershell, however this will not be possible when publishing the app in the marketplace.

Is there a way to have a package that contains everything including the code and have that uploaded to the Function App all using an ARM template in the Azure Marketplace?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should take a look at [Run-From-Zip](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/84). Basically, you host the zip package somewhere (typically storage blob), and in ARM template you just set a `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_ZIP` App Setting pointing to it.

As an alternative, you could use the ARM msdeploy extension, and point it to the zip package (e.g. something like [this](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/0c5a95ce5f0fdff7d4360b986059c7954d52ea68/ARMTemplates/FunctionsWebDeploy.json#L53-L65)).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out!

Comment: Yoo helped me. Thanks